# Intelligibly displaying multiple (dense) scatter plots on one axis in Python-Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to display scatterplots using Python and Matplotlib that plot data points belonging to one of several categories. I have decided to represent the categories by color with a legend, which makes for difficult tradeoffs between using symbols who are big enough that their colors are easily visible and symbols small enough to not excessively cover each other. (There are several thousand points at least)

However, I'm also running into another problem. I separate the categories into a set of numpy arrays, which I then plot one by one. This has the effect of making it look like there are many more points from the last category because it was plotted last so its points are on top. If I plotted all the categories at once relatively shuffled together, I wouldn't have this issue but I couldn't color-code the points. Increasing the window size helps, but doesn't totally solve it. Does anyone know of a good way to mitigate this? Is there some way to "shuffle" the data sets together or assign different colors to points in a single plot? I may just have to change my approach to visualizing this data.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered just using 4 plots instead of one? I think you have a bit too much data to reasonably fit into one graph. You may also want to consider switching to a log scale (unless you're already using dBs).

Comment: There are several different options, but the most effective ones all involve reducing/grouping the data in some way.  What do you want to emphasize most in the plot? 1) The envelope (e.g. similar to a "rolling max") of each category, 2) the number of points at a given frequency (e.g. a kernel-density-style histogram), or 3) the distribution of "peak heights" at each frequency interval (e.g. a boxplot/violin plot for each category at several frequency bins)?

Comment: If you just want a quick hack (that will result in a very cluttered plot!) you can always make each category partially transparent.  The end result will still be very messy, though.

Comment: Alternately, if you just want "shuffled" layers to the plot, you can just do something like `ax.scatter(all_x, all_y, c=category, marker='*', cmap=gist_heat-or-something-similar)`. You'll still have a messy plot, though, and you might need to shuffle your `all_x`, etc arrays.

Comment: The problem is, the point of displaying all this data on one set of axes is to quickly compare the categories with each other, and using separate plots kind of defeats this purpose. Joe, I'm a bit confused--how is the axes.scatter function used differently than the pyplot.plot function? (matplotlib seems to have a lot of duplicate functions and the documentation confused me) I'm looking at moving toward exporting the raw data to analyze and visualize in other programs, so this may become a moot point.

Comment: @dpitch40 - `scatter` colors and/or scales points by a 3rd/4th variable.  (The existance of separate `plot` and `scatter` functions is a result of matplotlib generally following matlab's api. Use `plot` when you just want to plot points or a line, and `scatter` when you need to color/scale the points by some other variable.)  Instead of 3 calls to plot, you'd have a single call to scatter.  With `scatter`, the points would be drawn in effectively random order, instead of in "layers".

Comment: @dpitch40 - As an example of "plot vs scatter" for something similar to your plot: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/6127799

Comment: How about changing your plot type to a box-and-whisker?